# ASP.NET Entity Framework model's Designer.cs file full of errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to use EF to link to a database on Visual Studio 2017.

What I did so far:
New Project **->** ASP.NET Web Application (C#) **->** Add folders and core references to "Web Forms" and "MVC" and set authentication to "Individual User Accounts"

Right click the project **->** Add **->** ADO.NET Entity Data Model **->** EF Designer from Database **->** New Connection **->** Server Name ".\SQLEXPRESS" **->** Selected database name **->** Finish

Following the generated comment in Designer.cs I changed the value of the 'Code Generation Strategy' designer property to 'Legacy ObjectContext', the comment was replaced with the code I need (according to the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2GF08Nj_rM&list=PLWrHdon6qnTbK92A3XwddVI8MwmdmKTl1&index=3) i'm using) and that's where the errors [showed up all over](https://gyazo.com/60aac062a6f2e943253e4e5e5e478cbd).

Not sure if I should post any code as I haven't added any yet, everything is still the automatically generated code.

Comment: it seems like you're missing the EF assembly reference

Comment: I tried the top answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651710/manually-adding-a-reference-to-entity-framework and this is what came up: https://gyazo.com/bde605bf9628d77b21980d0fa8d02955

Comment: Please don't use the legacy `ObjectContext` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for the problem I was facing earlier:**

Add ".Entity.Core." to the three tags as shown:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses;
```

**Note:** The tutorial and method are very much outdated and I found this very recent [tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/entity-framework-introduction-using-c-sharp-part-one/) a better solution